# Javascript just return text from an async/await/fetch

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I've seen [piles of theory answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), and no simple "just do this." At this point, the noise has buried the signal. Seriously. I'm buried in 100,000 words of text that I don't need.

Here's what I have:

```js
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = function1('/content.html');

function function1(url='') {
  if (url != '') {
    function2(url)
      .then( fromF2 => console.log(fromF2) );
  }
}

async function function2(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.text();
  }
}
```

`console.log(fromF2)` gives me perfectly valid html to the console. Would someone please just tell me the simple/stupid answer to get that perfectly valid html back up to `document.getElementById('content').innerHTML`?

Comment: TL;DR: you can’t.

Comment: `function2('/content.html').then(text => document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = text)`